# Applications of conchoids defined with respect to a non-linear curve?

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, curves, plane-curves

Most information on [conchoids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conchoid_(mathematics)) I have been able to find deal with a straight line (conchoid of Nicomedes). What work has been done on or using other types of conchoids? Are they used in any applications or other branches of mathematics? So far, I haven't been able to find anything. Any books or articles I should read?

Additionally, what are their most interesting or surprising properties?

For clarity, the line/curve I'm talking about is what one endpoint of a segment follows as its other endpoint traces the conchoid itself provided that the segment always passes through a given fixed point.

Comment: a good source : http://www.mathcurve.com/courbes2d.gb/conchoid/conchoid.shtml

Comment: The following also gives references to several curves. Columns of buildings had been designed of vertical cross section of this shape, but may not be in vogue today in that application.

 http://www.2dcurves.com/2dcurves.pdf